# Select all rows but only the latest (highest) version from database

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I want to retrieve all rows from the DB where the `OWNERKEY` is 1 but only the highest `DATAVERSION` of the `DATACONTROLID`.

In the example below I have two rows where `DATACONTROLID`= 1, they have 1 and 2 as `DATAVERSION`. I want to get the highest.

MyDB:

```
DATAKEY       OWNERKEY       OWNERTYPE      DATAVERSION   MALLKEY       DATAVALUE    DATAVALUETYPE   DATACONTROLID   DATADATE     DATATIME      DATASIGN
===========   ============   ===========   ===========   ===========   =========    ============    =============   ==========   ===========   =========     
4              1             2             1             1             1             2                1             2015-11-24   09:55:00:00   ADMIN
3              1             2             2             1             2             2                1             2015-11-23   20:55:00:00   ADMIN
2              1             2             1             1             3             2                2             2015-11-23   15:39:00:00   ADMIN
1              1             2             1             1             4             2                3             2015-11-23   11:29:00:00   ADMIN
```

Wanted result:

```
DATAKEY       OWNERKEY       OWNERTYPE      DATAVERSION   MALLKEY       DATAVALUE    DATAVALUETYPE   DATACONTROLID   DATADATE     DATATIME      DATASIGN
===========   ============   ===========   ===========   ===========   =========    ============    =============   ==========   ===========   =========     
3              1             2             2             1             2             2                1             2015-11-23   20:55:00:00   ADMIN
2              1             2             1             1             3             2                2             2015-11-23   15:39:00:00   ADMIN
1              1             2             1             1             4             2                3             2015-11-23   11:29:00:00   ADMIN
```

Where do I start?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDB
WHERE OWNERKEY = 1
```

Statement above is the obviuos part, but how do I proceed from that?

I think I should use `MAX(DATAVERSION)` somehow, but what to group on? And can I use both `*` and `MAX`?

Comment: Max function perhaps? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp has some notes that may be useful assuming the SQL is compatible.

Comment: I think you missed my edit. Anyhow, can I use both * and MAX() in a statement?

Comment: Yes, on the "Try it yourself" link from my previous comment here's a query that has both: `SELECT MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice,* FROM Products group by ProductID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example using `GROUP BY` in `MSSQL`:

```
SELECT  DATACONTROLID, 
        MAX(DATAVERSION) AS DATAVERSION, -- Note that 'AS' just gives the column a name in the result set, this isn't required.
        OWNERKEY
FROM    MyDB
WHERE   OWNERKEY = 1
GROUP BY DATACONTROLID, OWNERKEY
```

This is assuming that the `DATACONTROLID` determines 'distinct' records and `DATAVERSION` is the instance of the record.

This will group the `DATACONTROLID` column and return the `MAX(DATAVERSION)` for the grouped result. In this case, `DATACONTROLID = 1` has `DATAVERSION = 1 and 2`, so this returns 2.

It's worth noting that if you want to see additional columns in your result *and they're not aggregates such as `MAX()`*, then you'll need to add them to the `GROUP BY` clause - as I have done here with the `OWNERKEY` column. If you try to `SELECT OWNERKEY` without having it in the `GROUP BY`, you'll receive an error.

EDIT:

Here's a better way to accomplish the same result by using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyDB mdb
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  MAX(DATAVERSION) AS DATAVERSION,
            DATACONTROLID
    FROM    MyDB
    WHERE   OWNERKEY = 1
    GROUP BY DATACONTROLID
) AS mdb2 
    ON  mdb2.DATACONTROLID = mdb.DATACONTROLID 
        AND mdb2.DATAVERSION = mdb.DATAVERSION
```

What this does is turns the same `GROUP BY` statement that I showed you before into a filtering table. The `INNER JOIN` portion is selecting the `MAX(DATAVERSION)` and the `DATACONTROLID` it belongs to, and returning the result as the temp table `mdb2`.

This new inner table will return the following:

```
DATAVERSION DATACONTROLID
2           1
1           2
1           3
```

Then we're taking that result and getting all of the rows `(SELECT *)` that match this criteria. Since this inner table doesn't contain a result for `DATAVERSION = 1 where DATACONTROLID = 1`, this row gets filtered out.

Conversely, if you only wanted to see the *older* versions and not the newest, you can change this criteria to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and add `WHERE mdb2.DATAVERSION IS NULL`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyDB mdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  MAX(DATAVERSION) AS DATAVERSION,
            DATACONTROLID
    FROM    MyDB
    WHERE   OWNERKEY = 1
    GROUP BY DATACONTROLID
) AS mdb2 
    ON  mdb2.DATACONTROLID = mdb.DATACONTROLID 
        AND mdb2.DATAVERSION = mdb.DATAVERSION
WHERE mdb2.DATAVERSION IS NULL
```

Since we're selecting the `MAX(DATAVERSION)` in `mdb2`, it will contain null for the rows that don't meet this criteria.

Comment: This is close to the result. However I want to select all rows. Is it possible in this solution?

Comment: @JohanMagnusson I have updated the answer to reflect this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and all the explanation in you answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT OWNERKEY,DATACONTROLID,DATAVERSION,
               rank() over (partition by DATACONTROLID order by DATAVERSION desc) rnk
          FROM MyDB WHERE OWNERKEY = 1)
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note: I haven't tested, but this should work

Comment: I am confused. Can you give me some explanation please? What is rank() and rnk? Thank you

Comment: this is a window function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Window_function) in the sql standard sql-2003

Comment: Sure. What rank does is that it ranks data ordered and partitioned by determined fields. So in this case we are instructing to partition the data by DATACONTROLID, then for every partition to sort the data by DATAVERSION descending, and output how the record ranks amongst all other records within that partition. Since you only want the highest DATAVERSION, we are only interested in retrieving where the rank is 1 (highest since we ordered desc). And thats what we do by wrapping a select and filtering where rnk = 1.

Comment: No, it didn't work. BUT, it might be because i'm running Pervasive SQL and I don't know if they can handle the rank() function.

Comment: Note that this worked for me by adding `as rnk` before the outer `WHERE` clause. This is essentially performing the `GROUP BY` function and works well, but only returns the columns from the inner select and not the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDB
WHERE OWNERKEY = 1
and   DATAVERSION = 
      (SELECT max(DATAVERSION)
      FROM MyDB
      WHERE OWNERKEY = 1)
```

That works in some database environments; I hope yours! I learned that from "Introduction to SQL, Mastering the Relational Database Language", by Rick F. van der Lans. Pretty easy read.

Comment: The problem with this query is that it will return one row only since you're lacking a group by clause